# Add variables to an array within a function in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

So, I am trying to add variables to arrays which are relevant to each other, and since I like to program cleanly I would rather create a function (since I am not aware of any function that can add multiple values to different arrays) that I can pass 4 variables to in a specific order and it adds them to the corresponding arrays. This is better then having to count from the start of the arrays and find out which parts of the array correspond to each other. I tried using this code, but it does not appear to work. Although, if I try adding to the array from outside the function it appears to function properly. Here is my code:

```
<?php
function dbg($var1,$var2,$var3,$var4){
  $array1[] = "$var1";
  $array2[] = "$var2";
  $array3[] = "$var3";
  $array4[] = "$var4";
  echo count($array1);
}
dbg('foo','bar','ping','pong');
?>
```

Comment: You are filling 4 arrays with one entry each, that why you are not counting four.

Comment: `$array1` and `$array2` and `$array3` and `$array4` are __different__ arrays

Comment: Why do this in a function?  Makes little sense. Abandon this ship!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your problem is scope; if you do this within a function, you're creating and using four array variables which only exist *inside* the function. To allow them to have any effect outside of the function, simply define them as global:

```
<?php
function dbg($var1,$var2,$var3,$var4){
  global $array1, $array2, $array3, $array4;
  $array1[] = "$var1";
  $array2[] = "$var2";
  $array3[] = "$var3";
  $array4[] = "$var4";
  echo count($array1);
}
dbg('foo','bar','ping','pong');
?>
```

Comment: Might add `$GLOBALS['array1'][]  = $var1;`

Answer (score -1):

To add $var1 element to the $array1 array you should do like:
$array1[count($array1)] = $var1;

Answer (score -1):

In php less than 7 you can do

```
function dbg(){
      $args=func_get_args();
      print func_num_args();
      var_export($args);
}
```

with php 7  you can do

```
function dbg(...$args){
 print count($args);
 var_export($args);
}
```